# How to express "to raise your left shoulder up while lowering your right shoulder down and do the other way round repeatedly"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

When people dance, sometimes they raise their left shoulders up while lowering their right shoulders down and do the other way round repeatedly as shown in the picture.

What is the common term to express that movement, for example, **She raised her left shoulder up while lowering the right one and do vice versa repeatedly when singing**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

> She alternately raised her left and right shoulders while singing.

"Alternately" means "*two things continually following and succeeded by each other*", so this covers that the action is repeated. There is no need to mention that the shoulders are then lowered, as this is tacit in the action of repeatedly raising it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> She rocked her shoulders to the music.

It's not a perfectly unambiguous description, but it should work well for describing the action in a story.